# How to configure DNS in my ec2 instance?

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-ec2, bind

I used to use linode and this is what I had in db file:

```
ttl 86400
example.com. IN SOA li153-35.members.linode.com. foo.example.com. (
2011051301
21600
3600
604800
86400 )

example.com. IN NS li153-35.members.linode.com.
example.com. IN NS ns1.linode.com.

example.com. IN A 66.238.66.37
www IN A 66.238.66.37
* IN A 66.238.66.37
```

Then on my domain registrar I modified the dns of my domain with the linode ones. I have no idea what to use for my primary and secondary dns on ec2, doesn't ec2 has dns like linode used to offer? What should I do?

Answer (score 4):

Amazon offers a service called [Route 53](http://aws.amazon.com/route53/) to provide DNS service - this may be the simplest option for you, but it's not free; $1 per zone per month.

Alternatively, there are a number of services via other vendors that you could purchase, or host the DNS directly on your server itself.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How would I host the DNS directly? With bind? Do you have any resource on that please?

Comment: @Robert Look to configure BIND as "authoritative only", set up your zones with the BIND server as the `SOA` and `NS`, and configure glue records with your domain registration.  Do some research on these, and if you have specific questions or issues when working through it, post a question :).

Answer (score 1):

Ec2 instances may only use one IP address. This is a limitation for setting up master and slave servers on the same instance. I was trying to set up a DNS server on my own ec2 instance and I quit in favor to Amazon's [Route 53](http://aws.amazon.com/route53/#pricing). It offers this service at a cost which I consider quite reasonable.

If you still want to use BIND, consider installing web[m](http://webmin.com/)in to simplify the task.